# error submiting my app : "App Name has already been used"

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I was configuring the upload of my app in itunes connect but by accident I deleted the app ;( and now is I'm trying to configure again but I'm getting this error "App Name has already been used" . Any of you knows a way around this? o how can I fix this?

Comment: "Contact the app store" would be my advice.

Answer (score 1):

The App name, SKU and App Id can never be used again, but if it is any consolation, the name that appears under the app icon can always be whatever you want.